# How can you modify the url on a one page website?

Tags: javascript, html, web, user-experience

So I have my site here: http://darrenbachan.com/ and I want it where when I click on a project it adds a slug to the url so when I click on project A on the homepage it becomes http://darrenbachan.com/project-A. The way my site is currently built, it all resides in one html file.

What would I have to do, and rebuilding isn't really an option for me at this point, to make this work? Javascript? The UX of the site right now, it needs the project name because if you click on a project and want to go to the homepage I'd hit backspace, but in this case it won't do nothing forcing the user to click on "Back to Projects".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you aware that searching here on SO for `modify URL` gives you a list of answers?

Comment: `history.pushState`, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I did. You know, I honestly hate posting on this site, every post I make I get criticized. I have no other resources to help me. I've been stuck on my site for months because I do not know what I don't know. I tried googling to find answers for this and even looking up "modify URL" I see 90% of things I do not understand. I wish the person who marked this a duplicate posted the original so I can get some sort of help.